# php artisan list is not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

I am new in laravel. i need just list for all artisan commands, but i am getting this error

```
laravel-master$ php artisan list

[ErrorException]                                                  
  The use statement with non-compound name 'Session' has no effect
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this happen only then use `list` ? Try other artisan commands to verify

Comment: i tried all commands but i getting this error only... If i run composer update commands also finally getting this error...

Comment: Where are you trying to use session? Trying to use session anywhere outside controller like in config file or route? Look around

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use somewhere in your code:

```
use Session;
```

but you are not in any namespace.

You should verify in your code where you have this piece of code and remove this in file where you don't have

```
namespace ...
```

I suppose it's rather bug in your code than bug in Laravel and if you have something like this for example in controller, `artisan` command might behave like this until you fix the error.